# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in laravel 5.4 and it's not duplicated

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.4, models, relationships

So, guys, this is the error I am getting in my project.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of the file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Tf0.jpg

code for video model:-

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Video extends Model
{
public function videos(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Category");
}
```

Code for category model:-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{

}
```

Code for layouts.app:-

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="app">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Branding Image -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    &nbsp;
                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                        onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        Logout
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    @yield('content')
</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Code for vido.blade.php

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
      @section('content')
<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">
        <form id="addproduct" class="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="type">Custom Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vid_name" id="name" placeholder="Product Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="type">Video ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vid_id" id="Quantity" placeholder="Price">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control category" name="category" id="">
                <option value="">--select category--</option>
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->category}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  @endsection
```

Code for videocontroller:-

```
public function video(){
        $categories= \App\Category::all();

        return view('admin.video')
        ->with("categories",$categories);
    }

    public function addVideo(Request $request){
         $un= new \App\Video;
         $un->custom_name= $request->get('vid_name');
         $un->vid_id= $request->get('vid_id');
         $un->category= $request->get('category');
         $un->feature_status="0";
         $un->status="1";
         $un->save();
         if($un){
            return redirect()->back();
         }
    }
```

so guys I think i added all the code which is needed to know the error of my project. other thing is that when I remove category option from video form it works perfect. I don't know now that if it's error in my code or it's relationship error in models. please help......

Thanks in advance

Comment: In `Video.php`, missing closing bracket `}` at the end.

Comment: thanks lovepreet Singh for your help

Answer (score -2):

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Video extends Model
{
    public function videos() {
      return $this->belongsTo("App\Category");
    }
}
```